# Is it acceptable to have an invalid state in eventsourcing after event upgrading and before patching?

Tags: event-sourcing

Let say I have a stream of persisted events that build a valid state according to some "schema" I have defined.

I change the schema and the events are upgraded to reflect this.

However, some state could not be made valid just by upgrading events, I also needed to add more events to patch the state to make it fully valid.

Firstly, is this reasoning at all valid in terms of event sourcing?

If so, how do I handle cases where a specific version of a state no longer becomes valid? I mean is this acceptable? Should it still be possible to rehydrate a version with invalid state? If this is a write model and it's not the latest version, I could not modify this state anyway so maybee it's no big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, some state could not be made valid just by upgrading events, I also needed to add more events to patch the state to make it fully valid.

"Compensating events" is the usual term; there is a clerical error in the book of record, so we need to add a new event to the history that corrects the mistake.

> If so, how do I handle cases where a specific version of a state no longer becomes valid?

As a rule, you want to be wary, extremely wary, of introducing any automated validation that prevents you from loading an invalid history.  Remember, state is just state; the business rules constrain the way the domain is allowed to change.  Leaving broken states readable, but broken, is safe.

In particular, if you allow the state to load, it is a straight forward exercise to enumerate your event streams, test the final state of the object, and produce an exception report for any streams that produce an invalid state, escalating them to operators/management for handling, and so on.

Assuming that you are reasonable careful about input validation, and comparing whether your proposed command is consistent with latest known state (aggregates enforce business rules, but they don't need to hoard those rules for themselves), then you can probably achieve error rates low enough that you don't need aggressive data validation.  That's especially true when the errors are easy to detect and cheap to fix.

Failing that, freezing any aggregates while they are in an invalid state is a good way to prevent further damage.

But if you really need the state to stay valid, there's a trick that you can play with compensating events.

Consider: the basic pattern of event sourcing looks something like

```
History history = repository.getHistoryById(id)

State current = State.SEED

for (Event e : history) {
    current = current.apply(e)
}
```

There's actually a hidden concept here, which encapsulates the logic for processing the events prior to passing them to the state.  Hidden, because the null case just passes the enumerated events straight through to the target.

```
History history = repository.getHistoryById(id)
Historian historian = new Historian();

State current = State.SEED

for (Event e : historian.reviewEvents(history)) {
    current = current.apply(e)
}
```

The historian gives you a place to put your compensating event logic - based on its own state, the historian passes through most events, but fixes the ones that knows needs edits/compensation/redactions

Where does the historian state come from?  Why, from the history of the historian, of course.  You load the history of the event corrections, which will typically be short, into the historian, and then let the historian clean up the events for the aggregate.

And if you need corrections for the historian?  It's turtles all the way down!  Each stream has a unique historian; the identifier for the historian's stream is calculated from the stream it filters (named UUID's, for example, would allow you to do this).  So for each stream, you check to see if a historian stream exists; when you find one that doesn't, you know to stop searching and use the null historian, roll up the changes, process the final sequence of events to regenerate the state of your real object, and off you go.

Mind you, I haven't seen a reference implementation of this idea anywhere; it's whiteboard sound, but the truth is I've been deferring this requirement in my own designs.